# Using netcoreapp as dll instead of .NETStandard

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm coding a modular asp net core web api where each module has it's controllers and may have different dbContexts. The problem is I can't run migrations from .NETStandard dlls because its not supported:

> Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final is
>   not compatible with netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6).
>   Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final
>   supports:
>         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
>         - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
>         - netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)

so is there any drawback on creating netcoreapps and using them as if it where dlls?

Note: modules aren't referenced in any project (they are loaded at runtime) so I can't run migrations from other project/webhost/consoleapp. I could do a console app (.NETCoreApp) and reference all the modules and use it to create and run the migrations, but I preffer each module to manage its migrations.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can still change your NetStandard projects to NetCoreApp with an empty entry point and reference it in your main project. Or it is important to save them as DLL's?

Comment: @Toddams, That's what I'm asking. If there is any drawback in changing NetStandard modules to NetCoreapp. I mean, it seems that you can reference netstandard not only from netcore but net framework 4.5 onwards. If I change de dlls from netstandard to netcoreapp, I'll loose this compatibility, won't I? This isn't a feature I want to have right now, but it could be interesting to be able to call these module dlls also from desktop apps.

Comment: @Toddams,  I've just read here (https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/articles/standard/library) that netcoreapp will be compatible from net framework 4.6 onwards. So it seems not a big problem then.